# Nginx redirect to subdomain without changing the url

Tags: nginx, redirect, rewrite, hosting, website

I want to redirect www.example.com and example.com 
to ww.example.com in nginx

I tried a few things but ended up with a redirect loop
like 
return 302 $scheme://ww.example.com

Answer (score 0):

A redirection will necessarily change the URL, you are sending the client from example.com to ww.example.com. If you want to return ww.example.com content from example.com then you could just add an additional `server_name` directive to the same `server` block.

`return 302 $scheme://ww.example.com` will only result in a redirect loop if you have a further redirection on from that address. It seems that that is the address from which you want to serve your content so if you do have any redirections from it you should remove them.